# Generically non degenerate quadratic forms on a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme over an algebraically closed field (I'm mainly interested in the characteristic zero case), $V$ a rank $n$ vector bundle and $\ell$ a line bundle on $X$, and

$$\phi:V\otimes V\to\ell$$

an $\ell$-valued quadratic form on $V$, which can be seen as a map $\phi:V\to V^{*}\otimes\ell$. The form $\phi$ is *generically non degenerate* if it induces an isomorphism

$$\det(\phi):\det (V)\otimes\mathcal{O}(D)\to\det(V^{*})\otimes\ell^{\;n}$$

for some divisor $D$ on $X$.

My question is: is it possible for a form $\phi$ to be generically non degenerate yet not to induce an isomorphism $V\otimes\mathcal{O}(D)\to V^{*}\otimes\ell$ for some divisor $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X=\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb C}$, $V=O_X\oplus O_X(-1)\oplus O_X(-m)$ with $m\ge 3$, $\ell=O_X$ and consider the inclusion 
$$V\to V^*=O_X\oplus O_X(1) \oplus O_X(m).$$ 
It is generically non-degenerated, but $V\otimes O_X(k)$ is not isomorphic to $V^*$ for any $k$ (**edit** by Grothendieck's theorem on the classification of vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1$).

When $X$ is irreducible, non-degenerated just means that the map $\det(V)\to \det(V^*)\otimes \ell^n$ is not the zero map. This is not a strong condition.

Comment: I think non-degenerate means $\det(V)\to\det(V^*)\otimes\ell^{n}$ is *never* zero on $X$, and generically non-degenerate means it can be zero at most along a divisor. Right?  (assume $X$ irreducible)

Comment: (when I say the map is zero at a point $x$, I mean on the fiber at $x$ not at the stalk at $x$)

Comment: @Simplicius: as this is a map of invertible sheaves, if it is not identically zero, then the kernel is zero. The property is local, so you can suppose you are dealing with an $A$-linear map $A\to A$. Now think about the possibilities for the kernel.

Comment: Wait. I was talking about the map of bundles not the corresponding map of sheaves. Take for example an inclusion $\mathcal{O}(-1)\to\mathcal{O}$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$: it's an inclusion of sheaves (it's injective on stalks), but it is *not* an injective map of line bundles (it's *not* injective on *fibers*).

Comment: @Simplicius, OK I see.